# How to handle url in Multi Tenant application with web forms

Tags: c#, url, webforms, routes, url-routing

I have one application with is running on charnjeet.com/test/home and i have done it masking with url i.e www.abc.com.I have some issue with url i.e when i have open Product page i.e www.charnjeet.com/test/home/Product on www.charnjeet.com then it url is www.charnjeet.com/test/home/Product and but when I am try to open product page from www.abc.com then it url will be same i.e www.abc.com but page will be open i think it due to masking and it will be open is iframe.

But I want open same our on  www.abc.com/Product.Can any one help me.

Thanks